# why is repoquery not listing the files in a package

Tags: yum

`yum info eclipse-jdt` shows information about a package. However, `repoquery -lq eclipse-jdt` does not show me what files are in that package, as this transcript shows:

```
[tbrannon@oc bin]$ yum info eclipse-jdt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror refresh-
              : packagekit, security, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
KVM-WIN                                                  | 2.6 kB     00:00     
RHEL-6-x86_64-openafs                                    | 3.2 kB     00:00     
RHEL-6-x86_64-rational-linux                             | 2.6 kB     00:00     
RHEL-63-x86_64                                           | 3.7 kB     00:00     
RHEL-63-x86_64-updates                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00     
Installed Packages
Name        : eclipse-jdt
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 3.6.1
Release     : 6.13.el6
Size        : 26 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : RHEL-63-x86_64
Summary     : Eclipse Java Development Tools
URL         : http://www.eclipse.org/
License     : EPL
Description : Eclipse Java Development Tools.  This package is required to use
            : Eclipse for developing software written in the Java programming
            : language.

[tbrannon@oc bin]$ repoquery -lq eclipse-jdt
[tbrannon@oc bin]$
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable plugins for repoquery to work on Red Hat systems, otherwise it won't see packages from RHN. Try running

```
repoquery --plugins -l eclipse-jdt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run as root or via sudo and to add the option `--pkgnarrow=installed`. The `-q` option does nothing you can leave it out. Try this instead:

```
repoquery -l eclipse-jdt --pkgnarrow=installed
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting up the proxy resolved a repoquery hang:

```
# export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.spacely-sprockets.com:80
# export http_proxy=http://proxy.spacely-sprockets.com:80
# repoquery -i ...
```